# im trying to restart my hangman game using nodeJS, its saying that the variable I have is not a constructor -

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need my game to restart.  Everything is working fine.  But when I call the function to restart the game it would say

`displayProgress = new DisplayProgress();
displayProgress.checkGuess();`

`not a constructor`

I am new at this so please be patient:

Here is my checkGuess.js.
BUT YOU HAVE TOO CHECK THE OTHER MODULES:

playFunc.js - intializes the game.

profiler.js - gets data from word.txt to generate a random word

checkGuess.js (below) runs the game.

link provided:

heres the link to my github repo: [GITHUB](https://github.com/IamGiel/advancedJS)

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var inquirer = require('inquirer');
 var PlayFunc = require('./playFunc');
 var Player = require('./profiler');
 var lettersAlreadyTyped = [];
 var guessesLeft = 10;
 var goodLetters = [];
 var badLetters = [];


 function DisplayProgress(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;

  this.logInfo = function() {
  console.log("Name: " + this.name + "\nProfession: " + this.profession +
  "\nGender: " + this.gender + "\nAge: " + this.age + "\nStrength: " +
  this.strength + "\nHitPoints: " + this.hitpoints);
  console.log("\n-------------\n");
};
    this.checkGuess = function(){
        inquirer.prompt([
            {
            type: "input",
            name: "letter",
            message: "Type a letter to guess: "
            }
        ]).then(function(userInput) {

            letterTyped = userInput.letter.toLowerCase(); 
            if (!userInput.letter) {
                tryAgain();
            } 
            else {
                //LOGIC FOR HANGMAN
                var replaceArray = [];
                var correctLetters = [];

                //READING BLANKS.TXT
                fs.readFile('blanks.txt', "utf8",(err, data) => {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    underscores = data.split('');
                    //POPULATE 'lettersAlreadyTyped' ARRAY
                    lettersAlreadyTyped.push(letterTyped);
                    //FUNCTION WIN:
                    if ((underscores.join('') === currentString)) {
                        console.log("YOU WERE GREAT!");
                    }
                    //USE LOOP: PUSH BLANKS AND REPLACE BLANKS WITH LETTERS
                    for (var i = 0; i < underscores.length; i++) {
                        if (letterTyped === currentString[i]){//currentstring derived from playFunc.js
                        underscores.splice(i,1,letterTyped);//underscores (blanks) is the equivalent of currentstring (w/ letters)
                        correctLetters.push(i);
                        }
                        //DETECT REPEAT USER-INPUTS
                        if (correctLetters.length > 0){
                            usedLetter = true; //console.log("TRUE!!!");            
                        }
                        if(correctLetters.length === 0){
                            usedLetter = false; //console.log("FALSE!!!");  
                        }

                    }   //======= outside the for-loop =======//

                        //EXIT GAME IF USER-GUESS=0
                        if(guessesLeft <= 0){
                            console.log('\n\n\n==========\nSORRY, TRY AGAIN IN THREE DAYS, TAKE THIS TIME TO REFLECT ON WHAT YOU DID WRONG AND THINK :P\n==========\n\n\n');
                            return true;    
                        }

                    //PRINT THIS TO USER:
                    console.log("\n((((((((((((o))))))))))))((((((((((((o))))))))))))((((((((((((o))))))))))))\n\n\n");

                    //storing goodLetters/badLetters
                    if(usedLetter === true) {
                        goodLetters.push(letterTyped);
                    }
                    if(usedLetter === false){
                        badLetters.push(letterTyped);
                        guessesLeft--;
                        console.log("########### ---> OOOPS! TRY ANOTHER LETTER <--- ###########\n");
                    }
                    //SET UP FOR GOOD LETTER REPEATS
                    var goodL = goodLetters.join('');
                    for (var i = 1; i < goodLetters.length; i++) {
                        if(goodL.indexOf(letterTyped) > -1){
                            var good = true;    
                        }
                        else if (goodL.indexOf(letterTyped) === -1){
                            var good = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(good == true){
                        // console.log("you typed this already.");
                    }
                    if(good == false){
                        console.log("KEEP GOING! :)");
                    }
                    //SET UP FOR BAD LETTER REPEATS
                    var badL = badLetters.join('');
                    for (var i = 1; i < badLetters.length; i++) {
                        if(badL.indexOf(letterTyped) > -1){
                            var bad = true; 
                        }
                        else if (badL.indexOf(letterTyped) === -1){
                            var bad = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(bad == true){
                        console.log("wrong letter");
                    }
                    if(bad == false){
                        console.log("KEEP GOING! :)");
                    }
                    // console.log("CURRENT STRING " + currentString);
                    console.log("GUESSES LEFT:=====> " + guessesLeft);
                    console.log("YOUR PROGRESS:====> " + underscores.join(''));
                    // console.log("CORRECT LETTERS:==> " + correctLetters.length);
                    console.log("LETTER HISTORY:===> " + lettersAlreadyTyped.join(','));
                    console.log("\n\n\n((((((((((((o))))))))))))((((((((((((o))))))))))))((((((((((((o))))))))))))\n");
                    //looping through history of letters typed

                    //writing the updated user guesses
                    update = underscores.join('');
                    fs.writeFile("blanks.txt", update, (err) => {
                        if (err) throw err;
                    });

                    //recursion
                    DisplayProgress = new DisplayProgress();
                    DisplayProgress.checkGuess();
                    winner = underscores.join('').replace(/[^_]/g, "").length;
                        if (winner === 0) {
                            console.log("\n\n\n======================== ~~~~~~~~ YOU WIN!!! ~~~~~~~~ ========================");
                            restart();
                        }
                }); 
            }
        });
    }
}


//re-intitialize the game
function restart(){

    var blanksArr = [];
    var currentWord = [];
    var stackOv = "";
    fs.readFile("words.txt", "utf8", function(error, data){
        if (error) throw error;
        dataType = data.toLowerCase();
        //data in array
        var wordArr = dataType.split(',');
        //select random from word from data
        var compWord = wordArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArr.length)];//random
        //split chosen word
        var currentWord = compWord.split('');
        console.log("========================\n\n\n");

        //Looping through the word          
        for (var i = 0; i <= currentWord.length - 1; i++) {
            // pushing blanks 
            var gArr = blanksArr.push("_");


            //HYPHENS, COLONS, SPACES SHOULD BE PASSED
            stackOv = currentWord.join("").replace(/[^- :'.,]/g, "_");
            currentString = currentWord.join("");   
        }

        fs.writeFile("blanks.txt", stackOv, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("GUESS THIS MOVIE: \n\n\n" + stackOv);
            displayProgress = new displayProgress();
            displayProgress.checkGuess(); 
        });         
    });
}


function tryAgain() {
    inquirer.prompt([
      {
       type: "input",
       name: "letter",
       message: "NEED TO TYPE LETTER, or press 'ENTER' to END GAME"
      }

    ]).then(function(userInput) {
        var correctArray = [];
        // console.log(userInput.letter);
        letterTyped = userInput.letter;
        if (!userInput.letter) {
            console.log('goodbye'); 
        } else {
            //recursion
            DisplayProgress = new displayProgress();
            DisplayProgress.checkGuess();
        }
    });
}

module.exports = DisplayProgress;
```

Comment: Should be `new DisplayProgress();`, as it's case sensitive

Comment: You better believe what node.js says ...

Comment: I did that as well, part of my debug - but sadly - doesnt do it.  THANK THOUGH

Comment: @Teemu i trust node ;) just dont know how to satisfy its requirements

Comment: It may be because of the following line `DisplayProgress = new DisplayProgress()`, as that is now setting `DisplayProgress` to an instance

Comment: @user184994 that was the first focus of my debug, I changed variables many times, apparently this is not the case.  Although, what you are saying is very true.  That was the first analysis, but this is not whats causing the collapse of the app after user wins.

Comment: Uh, in `displayProgress = new displayProgress();` you don't want `displayProgress` to refer both to the instance and to the constructor (which doesn't work). Use two different variable names.